How to add the engulfing candle pair condition to appear in the previous box

I have written the box but I don't know how to search for the pair of engulfing candles inside the box when the price returns to the box.
How should I do that?
  skimb= close[2] < open[2] and close[1] > open[1] and close > open and close[1] > open[2] and low > high[2]    and spbar1
 var box[] skimbopen = array.new_box()
 var box[] skimbclose = array.new_box()
 barsupimb = ta.barssince(skimb)>=1

if skimb and ofzone
    array.push(skimbopen, box.new(bar_index - 2,low[2], bar_index + 20, high[2], extend=extending,   bgcolor=zone , border_width=0,
      text = 'oSK ', text_size = size.tiny, text_halign = text.align_right, text_color = color.white, text_font_family = font.family_monospace))

//---engufing ----conditon
   candle = close[1] < open[1] and close > open and close > open[1]

   if engul =  close[1] < top and close[1] > bottom

  Plotshapr ( engul , title="en "......)

